# Onclck listener with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

1. Hello, So I followed the Android Developer website to create some
   simple tabs in Android with fragments. The tabs fully work and
   display the content they are supposed to. However, I am now trying
   to intergrate it with this [AndroidHive Login tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). I have
   set up the XML properly and the MainActivity from the Login tutorail
   now shows on my first tab. I am now trying to setup the onclick
   listener for the logout button but it seems my intent params are not
   working and also the finish method doesn't work:

   ```
   private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);    
    db.deleteUsers();
    Intent intent = new Intent(OneFragment.this, LoginActivity.class);     
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();  
   }
   ```

   I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that my clsss isnt an
   activity?

   ```
   public class TabOne extends Fragment implements  View.OnClickListener {.....}
   ```
2. Also I am not following his tutorial exactly and am coding some elements of the project how I prefer it (I've been studying pure Java at university for 2 yeats now). But inside his MainActivity class he has to variables as follows (the classes are available in his login tutorial)

   - private SQLiteHandler db;
   - private SessionManager session;

and he initalises them in the onCreate as follows:

```
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
```

However, because I am using fragments and not activities I can't do this so after some researching I tried this:

```
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

It has removed the errors on Android Studio but I am not 100% sure it will work (I still have the above error in my code so I am unable to test) - Can you please clarify if this would work also - again all his classes are in the link above including session and sqllite.

Edit 1 - Sorry I should have added this, I used cases and called the logout method:

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnLogout:
            logoutUser();
    }
}
```

Thank you, if any further information is required please ask and I shall update this post

Comment: It is a good practice to use a break statement after each case. look at my answer below it should solve your problem.

Comment: @Salvatory Baya Ah sorry yes i forgot to add the break statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access your main activity context from the fragment to able to call methods which belong to activity class. for your case use the folowing

```
private void logoutUser() {
  session.setLogin(false);    
  db.deleteUsers();
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);     
  startActivity(intent);
  getActivity().finish();  
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate this segment of code it fixed my problem. Sorry for the basic question I am still learning android development - when we say getActivity() how does it know to go to the MainActivity? Again thanks a lot! this worked

Comment: @AmberHelpSK Each fragment is hosted by an activity, Android keeps track of all activities with their associated fragments. Therefore when you call getActivity() from a fragment. It will know which activity context to get.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if my way of getting the Application's Context is the correct way, but I have created a public method in my MainActivity (that shows the Fragments) that returns the application context. If you go this route, you can call `MainActivity.getContext()` (or the name of your method) and can get that Activity's context inside of your fragment.

Comment: Ill try this, do not fully understand it though